# webpack + react + config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm pretty new using this technologies and there is a thing I need to achieve and I can't do it.

When I build my react project, webpack chunks all the files in a couple of javascripts. 
I have many URL's defined (for example endpoint URL's to access some services).
My idea is to copy this build to different environments (qa, prod) and modify the values of the URL. 
The IMPORTANT thing here is that I'll not have the URL's from prod, so I'll need a configuration file outside all the chunked javascripts where I can reference from my project.

Basically what I want is to have a json file outside all the js chunked file and use it from a react component for example.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a great use case for ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES. Is that an option or no? You do something like API_ROOT="prod.test.com";, API_ROOT="qa.test.com"; and API_ROOT="dev.test.com"; on the build server and your app will use the API_ROOT environment variable to get the url.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your point but I need it in runtime, not in build time. One build for multiple environments, then a different file for each environment will be the difference. 
The thing is that PROD environment will be handled by other team and they don't want to share with me their URL's

Comment: Create a "config" json file, use a loader to keep the file intact (file-loader), tadam...

Comment: @MatheusSilva I tried that, The file keeps intact but I'm not able to import it from my app.js. I've tried using require, import and also trying to use fetch function without success. Any example?

Comment: If you use a json file, import that normally as you would require a normal js file, doesnt work? You would have at the final build a file called `something.hash.json` or something like that